# How to set default app for a file extension in terminal on macOS mojave?

Tags: macos, file, terminal, default

I have developed an application for macOS Mojave which saves / opens custom files with specific extension. I am going to ship the application, and would like the application opens when the customer double clicks on the files provided. I am aware that the customer can do it using GUI in Finder, but I would like to establish the association of file extension and application during installation.

Of course it can be done in GUI easily, but I am looking for command line solutions.
Also, the solution provided here does not seem to be working on Mojave.
https://superuser.com/questions/273756/how-to-change-default-app-for-all-files-of-particular-file-type-through-terminal